# Multithreading in spring

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

I am trying to get into spring multithreading and I have few questions.

I have runnable method in ThreadRating class. Now I am not sure about the best way of using it.

**option 1 I found:**

```
private void updateRating() {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // test
        // thread part
        Runnable worker = new ThreadRating(path, i, products.get(i), dao, fileHandler);
        executor.execute(worker);
    }
    executor.shutdown();
    try {
        executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        log.error("There was an error when ending threads");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    System.out.println("Finished all threads");
}
```

This seem to be running fine. After the for loop, it waits until threads are finished and ends.

**Second option I tried**

```
private TaskExecutor taskExecutor;

public UpdateBO(TaskExecutor taskExecutor) {
    this.taskExecutor = taskExecutor;
}

private void updateRating() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // test
            Runnable worker = new ThreadRating(path, i, products.get(i), dao, fileHandler);
            taskExecutor.execute(worker);
        }
    // wait for threads to be finished before you go any further ??
        }
```

And in xml file I have

```
<beans:bean id="taskExecutor"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <beans:property name="corePoolSize" value="5" />
    <beans:property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
    <beans:property name="queueCapacity" value="25" />
    <beans:property name="waitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown" value="true" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="updateBO" class="UpdateBO">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="taskExecutor" />
</beans:bean>
```

And here are my questions:

1. Is there any difference between these two options? Speed, memory, possible leaks? Or are they the same just written differently?
2. Do I need to shutdown the pool when using webservice? I know that in the second option I don't have to, but is it the same when using webservice?
3. When using second option - how should I tell to wait there until all jobs are finished? In the first option I just shut the pool down and wait to finish. But in the second option the code request is finished before the tasks are completed.
4. `executor.execute(worker);` - just to clarify. This is not actually creating a new thread, but it adds task to a queue and if the queue is full it waits right on this line in the code until there is free place?

Thanks for helping me understand.

Comment: Shutting down pool executors is not good options at all, in some environments such as app server with enabled security option attempt to shutdown executor will cause security exception. If you need to wait workers until they finish, use `Future`s instead of `Runnable`s.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Main difference: in option 1) you create new executor on every
   `updateRating()` call, in option 2) executor is created once on deployment
   time, you feed the same single executor with new jobs. Second approach is much better.
2. Why do you need to shut down the executor? **Creating new executors
   and shutting them down to wait until task is processed is antipattern**. Remember, that *executors are created in order to control system resources* and should be treated such. (E. g. you have DB connection pool of 50 connections - so to serve DB access you create executor of 50 threads - to avoid connection limit exceed. Or you have 24 cores on server and need to parallelize work in the best possible way).

   And, as I mentioned in comment, in some environments (such as app servers) you often have no rights to shut down executor. Such attempt will produce `SecurityException`.
3. If you need to wait until workers finish their jobs, wrap every job with `Callable` instead of `Runnable`, then from main thread call corresponding `future.get()` - and it will block
   until job finishes. Timeouts are supported. [Example](http://www.journaldev.com/1090/java-callable-future-example)
4. Absolutely right. Threads are created and destroyed by executor itself, when it thinks is best time to. Try to monitor your app with *jvisualvm* to see how it happens.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. One more question about the pool - as far as I understand, spring handles that for me. So if I want to use threads in multiple classes, I just change bean configuration to  <beans:bean id="updateBO" class="UpdateBO, ..... more classes to come ?"> and it will handle for all the classes at once? -> I can call it at the same time from multiple classes it will multiply or I get the same pool?

Comment: Not exactly. One bean - one class. For another classes that need this executor, you need to define another beans, passing this particular executor bean as constructor argument.

Answer (score 3):

1.) Option 1 is badly implemented since you define your executor service locally and close it after each use. This defeats the purpose of creating a thread pool - it needs to be a global object, so Option 2 is the way to go.

2.) You don't need to shut down the executor service when calling a web service. If the webservice does not respond the call will eventually time out and the thread fill complete execution. If you shut down the executor service, it won't be available for the next call.

3.) If you need some form of notifcation once your thread has finised, you should use [Callable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) in conjuction with [Futures](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) instead.

4.) Your executor service has a maximum of 10 threads allocated, it won't spawn off more than those. If all of them are busy, you task will idle until one of those threads becomes available.

Comment: and actually I don't need any notification, just wait for them to finish. Futures seems to do that for Runnable as well.